# Special characters supported in bcrypt encryption

Tags: c#, bcrypt

In our application, we are using bcrypt for hashing the credentials.

What are all the special characters accepted other than available special characters in keyboard?

For example, i have analysed about dash https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash . In this link there are many types in dash. Is these all kind of dash will be allowed in bcrypt?

I just want to confirm all other special characters list regarding this.

Comment: Why do you expect bcrypt to not support special characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bcrypt works on bytes, not on characters, so the characters supported by bcrypt are the characters supported by whatever encoding you're using.

If you're using Latin-1 as your encoding, the supported characters will be all Latin-1 characters. If you're using a Unicode encoding, such as UTF-8, then the supported characters will be all Unicode characters.